# Fetching images from gallery- able to fetch without any permission

Tags: android, gallery, android-permissions, android-gallery, user-permissions

Using below code to fetch images from gallery

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.action = Intent.ACTION_PICK
intent.type = "image/*"
if (multiImageAllowed) intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
context.startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_GALLERY)
```

When i use this intent, it show me chooser with multiple apps, i select one of the app and get an image, and show it in my app,(i get the image in onActivityResult), these app have their own runtime permission checks.
Do i need to add gallery permission check in my app too ?
if it's required then why android is not stopping me or giving an exception.
Is it just a good convention to ask user for permission when he/she intentionally opening an app to add images ?

so my question is , should i add runtime permission in my app too or is it not required.(since those apps are handling it anyway, and i can not access more image than the one he/she selects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> using below code to fetch images from gallery

If you wish to have the user pick content based on MIME type, use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. `ACTION_PICK` is to have the user pick content based on a particular collection, identified by a `Uri` in the `Intent`. This is why [the `ACTION_PICK` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PICK) mentions that the input is a `Uri` and does not mention anything about MIME type.

> Do i need to add gallery permission check in my app too ?

I am guessing that you are referring to `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. In theory, a `Uri` returned by `ACTION_PICK`, `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` should be usable without additional permissions, at least [for a short time](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html).

However, not everybody plays by the rules, so IMHO it is safest if you hold `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. If you are concerned about asking your users for that permission, you could try delaying it — try using the `Uri`, and if you get a `SecurityException`, then ask for the runtime permission. Then try using the `Uri` again if the user grants that permission. Personally, I would aim for better reliability and would request `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` first.

Comment: hmmm, interesting.

Comment: but isn't that request incorrect, i am asking user to have access to his storage (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) but in actual am not even reading his external storage, it's the other app that has access to all his data, i have the access to the only one image that the other  app returns(which the user selects).

Comment: @Bawa: Yes, but the other app might require your app to hold `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.